# Generation of Borel sigma-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

I want to show that the Borel sigma-algebra over $\mathbb R^n$ can be generated by A, the set of closed sets of $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. $A = \{C \subset \mathbb R^n$ : C is closed$\}$.

I could show that this statement holds true in $\mathbb R$. Is there a theorem or something like that which I can use to deduce that if the statement is true in $\mathbb R$, it's also true in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: The question as it stands doesn't make sense, a $\sigma$-algebra needs to generated by set of subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, not a single subset. So in what sense can this set of subsets be closed? Do you mean that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by all closed subsets of $\mathbb R^n$? In which case this follows trivially since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the open subsets and is closed under complements.

Comment: I edited my question a bit. :)